# CAST as float with local variable SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
`declare @totalItems int,
@totalPeople int,
@averageThings float;

select @totalItems = count(*) from table1
select @totalpeople = count(*) from tblvisits
select @averageThings = cast(@totalItems/@totalPeople as float)

select @averageThings, @totaPeople, @totalItems
```

This returns an integer instead of a float, I tried with and without the `cast as float` and got the same results, how to make it return a float

Comment: Is `@averagecomorbids` the same thing as `@averageThings`?

Comment: good catch, it was and it edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it returns a float. The value of the float may be an integer, but the type is a float. Which also answers your real question: you must perform the division using float operands, not cast the result of int division to float:

```
declare @totalItems float,
   @totalPeople float,
   @averageThings float;

select @totalItems = count(*) from table1
select @totalpeople = count(*) from tblvisits
select @averagecomorbids = @totalItems/@totalPeople;

select @averageThings, @totaPeople, @totalItems;
```

Your code will break with divide_by_zero if `tblvisits` is empty...

Comment: Not that my database is anywhere near large enough to matter, but are there any performance issues when assigning a local variable as type float when it's an integer in reality?

Comment: for doing a single division it doesn't matter, irrelevant of the size of the operands. If you would do a float division for every row in a table with 1B rows then we'd have something to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're doing the division in integers, and *then* converting the result to `float`. Maybe:

```
declare @totalItems int,
@totalPeople int,
@averageThings float;

select @totalItems = count(*) from table1
select @totalpeople = count(*) from tblvisits
select @averageThings = @totalItems/cast(@totalPeople as float)

select @averageThings, @totaPeople, @totalItems
```

To force one of the arguments to be a `float` before the division occurs, which will then force the division to be done as `float` instead.

---

And, as a minor quibble:

> This returns an integer instead of a float

No, it returns a `float`. But one that always happens to have an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast each part

```
  cast(@totalItems as float)/cast(@totalPeople as float)
```

Right now it's doing the division with integers and getting an integer result before the cast.

Comment: You only *need* to cast one part. And when posting code, it's nicer if you indent by four spaces, surround with backticks, or just highlight it and hit the `{}` button.